# Vectr doesn't launch on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snap

I installed a software called Vectr through the snap store on Ubuntu 19.04 using the command.

```
sudo snap install vectr
```

The program installs as usual, and I get this message on the terminal,

```
vectr 0.1.15 from Vectr* installed
```

The problem arises when I try to launch the application. It doesn't open at all. No matter how many times I click on it or start it through the terminal, it does not launch. I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 as well. What should I do?

Comment: Remove it. If you launch it from the terminal, you'll see that it will fail to create a directory in your home directory plus it will also fail due a wrong instruction being executed. There is a 32 and 64 bit version but I didn't bother to try the 32bit version. It has low reviews on the Software Center.